# Show notification when answers are moved (along with rep)

Tags: feature-request, reputation, notifications, migration

Today, I visited Stackoverflow to discover that I had lost reputation from the last time I had been there. I didn't have any new notifications of any sort and my history didn't show any downvotes or anything.. So I was completely perplexed..

Then, I was reading some stuff on Super User and found something I had answered. The question got moved from SO to SU along with my reputation I had gotten before(I had 3 upvotes+accepted before the move).

I propose that we have some sort of notification for when our answers get moved from one site to another, especially if it involves moving reputation along with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe others view this differently, but I can't really see any benefit in this.

Whether you win or lose reputation while you're away isn't actually relevant, because there is nothing to react to, or correct. Hence, there is no need for a notification. The same goes for a question that you answered and that was moved since, **edit**: As long as there is some means to find out what happened to your answer, which does not seem to be the case at the moment.

I would not want to receive any such information.

Comment: If you can't find your question it's a big problem though.

Comment: @Koper true, the asker should be notified somehow.

Comment: And the response is mod-deleted, so you can't even see your answer in your list of responses for your user account.. so if you think of something and want to edit that answer, you now can't find it...